# How to bundle a Native Host with Chrome Extension and publish it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-native-messaging

I'm publishing a Chrome Extension that uses Native Messaging with a java application but it says that i cannot upload a double manifest ( one for the extension, the other one for the native host installation).
The only solution that i thought is to include the manifest of the java app inside the extension manifest (but i'm not sure it's possible, could you confirm please) OR to upload somewhere else the native host app (including its manifest) and let the user to download and install it. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome extensions cannot include additional software which runs outside Chrome, like native host apps.

You will need to distribute your Java application (and its associated application manifest) separately from the Chrome extension.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is it possible to include a manifest into another? This way i should be able to include the java app manifest inside the chrome extension but probably is against the market policy..

Answer (score 0):

You can't include multiple manifest files.
For native message host, please try to refer this link

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host